# Showing selected option in dropdown with opt-group on page load AngularJS is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, optgroup

When I try to show default selected value it doesn't show up i.e the option does not get selected in dropdown. The default value is coming from database and I'm setting that value in the model variable `pageData.fields[content.id].key`
Following is the sample JSON that I'm using to populate the dropdown:

```js
$scope.dropdownFields = [{
    groupName: 'PAGE',
    isOptDisabled: false,
    items: [{
        name: 'PageName1',
        type: 'page'
      },
      {
        name: 'PageName2',
        type: 'page'
      },
      {
        name: 'PageName3',
        type: 'page'
      },
      {
        name: 'PageName4',
        type: 'page'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'COLOR',
    isOptDisabled: false,
    items: [{
        name: 'COLOR1',
        type: 'component'
      },
      {
        name: 'COLOR2',
        type: 'component'
      },
      {
        name: 'COLOR3',
        type: 'component'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: 'OTHERS',
    items: [{
        name: 'Bold',
        type: 'others',
        isOptDisabled: false,
        itemList: [{
            name: 'Yes',
            value: true
          },
          {
            name: 'No',
            value: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'Italic',
        type: 'others',
        isOptDisabled: false,
        itemList: [{
            name: 'Yes',
            value: true
          },
          {
            name: 'No',
            value: false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

```html
<select id="{{content.id}}_filter" ng-model="pageData.fields[content.id].key" class="form-control" ng-change="onChangeFilter(pageData.fields[content.id].key, content.id)">
  <option value="">[Select an option]</option>
  <optgroup ng-repeat="header in dropdownFields" label="{{ header.groupName }}">
    <option ng-repeat="item in header.items" value="{{ item.name }}" ng-disabled="isDisabled(header.groupName, item.name)">{{ item.name}}
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Is there any way to do this as I've researched a lot on this but the solutions were with ng-options and I cannot use ng-options for creating the dropdown due the disability functionality. The AngularJS version that I'm using is 1.2
Any suggestion into the direction will be appreciated. Thanks.
**EDIT:** The code is successfully populating the dropdown and I'm able to get the value of selected option as well. But I'm not able to set an option by default into the dropdown. For eg. `PageName3` is already selected in the dropdown.
**EDIT2:** So far now I'm able to show default value selected in this combobox on button click(here's the [plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/IlJlFAIA3r1FlLcBl2EA?p=info)) but I'm not able to set this value when I redirect from another page to this page.
So it goes like this, on this page(say PAGE1) I fill in these values there are multiple such dropdowns and textboxes in front of them for values, then I pass these values to the next page(say PAGE2); on PAGE2 I have a back button on the click of this button I return to PAGE1 with the same values passed before and I've to set all these values back as it were before. This is where I'm stuck! Not able to set selected values in dropdown while setting textboxes is done.

Comment: you can not use ex. Angular 1.4? With 1.4 it works : http://plnkr.co/edit/2AaOYhFzsefy3DYIGg64?p=preview

Comment: Well RN I cannot update angular version :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add default option into dropdown like so:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected"></label><br/>
       <select ng-model="item.name" ng-click="onChangeFilter(item.name)" class="form-control" >

        <optgroup ng-repeat="header in dropdownFields" label="{{ header.groupName }}">
            <option ng-selected="selected">Greetings!</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in header.items">{{item.name}}</option>

        </optgroup>
      </select>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vszVo3BHEA3T4yxGSUkA?p=preview

Comment: I guess my question is misleading will update it. But my question is to have one option as selected by default in the dropdown.

Comment: @Diksha Look now - is it what do you mean?

Comment: The value is not hardcoded as you've shown the value is set from the JSON itself

Comment: Hey @BartoszTermena I've updated my question can you take a look?